# Using tags in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking

It is really necessary to have all these tags:

```
ga('require', 'linkid');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
```

Isn't this tag enough?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX', 'auto');
```

In my analytics and Woocommerce, I already configure ecommerce tracking, so is the tag `ecommerce` still necessary?

Comment: If you have integrated Google Analytics via the Woocommerce GA plugin you probably will not need any code at all, it should be enough to set your account id in the plugin settings.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a bit of deduction:

1. The `ga('create', 'UA....')` line is required to create the analytics tracking object. It has (practically) nothing to do with ecommerce. Assuming you aren't already implementing your GA tracking through another WP plugin (like you are with Woocommerce), then that line is necessary.
2. Same thing for the `ga('send', 'pageview')` line - that's for sending in a pageview hit. Without that on all pages, then you won't get accurate data.
3. `ga('require', 'linkid')` is not necessary for standard tracking or for ecommerce. That is used for enhanced link attribution.
4. So what your question really comes down to is whether `ga('require', 'ecommerce')` is required. The answer is "no", if you are already tracking ecommerce through the Woocommerce plugin.